# HERE-API get for sequence optimization does not return

Tags: python-requests, here-api

I'm trying to optimize the sequence of some waypoints with the here-api and the findsequence.json-API.

My code looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# coding: utf8

from requests import Request, Session
import requests


class HereConector:
    app_id = "get_your_own_app_ip"
    app_code = "get_your_own_app_code"

    sequence_url = "https://wse.cit.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json"

    container_locations = [(u'Hamburg', [53.551086, 9.993682]), (u'Munich', [48.13715, 11.576124]), (u'Berlin', [52.520008, 13.404954]), (u'D', [51.514244, 7.468429])]

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # small proof that the process can work
    def get_demo_route(self):
        url = "https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json"
        # app_data = {"app_id": self.app_id, "app_code": self.app_code}
        app_data = {"waypoint0": "52.5,13.4", "waypoint1":"52.5,13.45", "mode": "fastest;car;traffic:disabled"}
        app_data['app_id'] = self.app_id
        app_data['app_code'] = self.app_code
        print (requests.get(url, app_data).json())


    def loc_to_waypoint(self, location):
        return str(location[1][0]) + ',' + str(location[1][1])

    def find_sequence(self):
        app_data = {"app_id": self.app_id, "app_code": self.app_code}
        app_data['start'] = self.loc_to_waypoint(self.container_locations[0])
        for i, cl in enumerate(self.container_locations):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            app_data['destination' + str(i)] = self.loc_to_waypoint(cl)
            if i == 10:
                break

        app_data['end'] = self.loc_to_waypoint(self.container_locations[-1])
        app_data['mode'] = 'truck;fastest'

        s = Session()
        req = Request('GET', url=self.sequence_url, params=app_data).prepare()

        # This URL can be copy/pasted into a browser and returns an optimized sequence
        print (req.url)

        # this call blocks
        r = s.send(req)

        # this call also blocks
        # r = requests.get(self.sequence_url, app_data)

        print (r.json())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    hc = HereConector()
    hc.get_demo_route()
    hc.find_sequence()
```

If I copy the generated URL into my browser, I get an optimized route immediately (processing time < 200ms) so the url and parameters should be right. However, the call to s.send (or requests.get(self.map_view_url, app_data)) blocks. (other calls e.g. to get maps work perfectly with requests).

This is also my first experiment with the requests-library so I don't know how to debug further.

Update: Code shows same behavior for python2.7 and python3

Comment: Would you check your python version?
Then we can try it with your python version.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: (but using python3 also doesn't help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried executing your above code and see the below response using both s.send and requests.get calls. So the issue doesn't seem to be with the code. Could you please check your credentials and the respective number of requests you can make using it. It could be that you are exceeding your quota and hence the request is blocking. Try with different app id and code.

```
{'results': [{'waypoints': [{'id': 'start', 'lat': 53.551086, 'lng': 9.993682, 'sequence': 0, 'estimatedArrival': None, 'estimatedDeparture': None, 'fulfilledConstraints': []}, {'id': 'destination2', 'lat': 52.520008, 'lng': 13.404954, 'sequence': 1, 'estimatedArrival': None, 'estimatedDeparture': None, 'fulfilledConstraints': []}, {'id': 'destination1', 'lat': 48.13715, 'lng': 11.576124, 'sequence': 2, 'estimatedArrival': None, 'estimatedDeparture': None, 'fulfilledConstraints': []}, {'id': 'destination3', 'lat': 51.514244, 'lng': 7.468429, 'sequence': 3, 'estimatedArrival': None, 'estimatedDeparture': None, 'fulfilledConstraints': []}, {'id': 'end', 'lat': 51.514244, 'lng': 7.468429, 'sequence': 4, 'estimatedArrival': None, 'estimatedDeparture': None, 'fulfilledConstraints': []}], 'distance': '1484517', 'time': '68916', 'interconnections': [{'fromWaypoint': 'start', 'toWaypoint': 'destination2', 'distance': 289082.0, 'time': 13845.0, 'rest': 0.0, 'waiting': 0.0}, {'fromWaypoint': 'destination2', 'toWaypoint': 'destination1', 'distance': 591003.0, 'time': 27227.0, 'rest': 0.0, 'waiting': 0.0}, {'fromWaypoint': 'destination1', 'toWaypoint': 'destination3', 'distance': 604430.0, 'time': 27844.0, 'rest': 0.0, 'waiting': 0.0}, {'fromWaypoint': 'destination3', 'toWaypoint': 'end', 'distance': 2.0, 'time': 0.0, 'rest': 0.0, 'waiting': 0.0}], 'description': 'Targeted best time; without traffic', 'timeBreakdown': {'driving': 68916, 'service': 0, 'rest': 0, 'waiting': 0}}], 'errors': [], 'processingTimeDesc': '940ms', 'responseCode': '200', 'warnings': None, 'requestId': None}
```

Comment: I tried it again with the same app_id/code as before and now got the same result (with 'driving': 68916) as you. I read about the 10 sequence-calls for the freemium, but that was not the issue (I executed the link in the browser around 15 times after the python-call failed until I got the message that I reached the limit). Even after reaching the limit, the API is still returning data with an error code (saying that it won't deliver a sequence) but my call just blocked. Thanks for looking into the problem and running my code!